# Why my elements are not positioned in line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is mysite:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/

This is code HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>      
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      <p> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is example:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_stacked_to_hor&stacked=h

[image]

In the example above elements are positioned in line and when you resize the window go below.

To me unfortunately are positioned below.

What's wrong? I copied the code exactly as it was there.

I put a picture to better understand how they look at me?

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) supports four size tiers for different display sizes and you are currently just using one:

> The Bootstrap 3 grid system has four tiers of classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). You can use nearly any combination of these classes to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

To get the same effect on multiple size tiers, you can add more tiers by adding classes like so:

`<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6"`

Comment: I add what you said and everything appears below.Can you give a screnshot please?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it look like you don't have all the bootstrap component in your website configuration.

Looking at your "head" with Chrome Inspector, i couldn't find any complete Bootstrap CSS-related.

Add class "text-center" for example, on a row. Normally, your text would be centered.

Comment: I added some text in a row and this row, I centered using text-align: center;